# How to make a UIButton detect it's been pressed?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have a `GameViewController` class and a `GameBoardView` class.

In `GameViewController` I create *n X m* objects from class `CSquare`. This will conform a GameBoard. This objects are drawn on screen (and actually fill it) because for each square I do `[self.view addSubview: square]`.

`GameViewController`is `GameBoardView`'s delegate. Inside `GameBoardView` I have implemented the `touchesEnded` method, and here there's a message sent to the delegate (ie, `GameViewController`) so that "control" is transferred back to `GameViewController`. So I capture "touches" from `GameBoardView` and send them to `GameViewController` in order to be handled for whatever methods are there.

The problem came when I created, from the storyboard, a `UIButton` called `settingsButton`. I'd like this `settingsButton` to be on top of the GameBoard, so that it can always be pressed.

However, even though I created an outlet `IBOutlet UIButton *settingsButton`and action `(IBAction)settingsButtonPressed:(id)sender` in `GameViewController`, whenever I touch the screen, the touch is "captured" by `touchesEnded`, and it never detects the ´SettingsButton´ has been hit. Actually, the action `settingsButtonPressed` is never called.

I tried a couple of things:

- Set the `settingsButton` as first responder doing `[_settingsButton becomeFirstResponder];` **after** all the squares have been created and added as a subview to the `GameViewController`'s view. Didn't work.
- Do `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:_settingsButton];`.

None of them work. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

**Update:** I managed to get it to work, and realized where my mistake was.

In `viewDidLoad` I was inadvertently creating two UIViews:

```
GameBoardView *View = (GameBoardView*)self.view;
View.delegate = self;
(...)
GameBoardView *GBView = [[GameBoardView alloc] initwithFrame:frame];
[self.view addSubview:GBViwe];
```

I still don't understand why doing `[self.view bringSubviewToFron:_SettingsButton];` was not working properly with the code above. However, deleting the GBView-related lines made everything work ok.

Thanks everyone for the comments.

Comment: `[super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];`

Comment: Looks suspicious. Did you really connect button with you controller's action in IB? Try to check twice that `settingsButton` outlet is actually connected in IB and button itself stays on top at the moment you get this error. Change you code (temporarily maybe) to use gesture recognizers instead of manual handling of touches.

Comment: @H2CO3: I don't know where do you propose I add this line.

Comment: @hoha As far as I know, the button is well connected. I drag the `UIButton` to the `GameViewController`, right-click on it, I select `Touch Up Inside`, and drag it again to `GameViewController`'s interface. Can you elaborate on what are gesture recognizers?

Comment: @FerranMG Obviously in the overridden `-touchesEnded:withEvent:` method.

Comment: @FerranMG http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html . For simple things (like tapping, dragging, rotating, etc.) gesture recognizers provide a more concise and robust way of doing touch event handling. Maybe in your case it is still required to use `touches...` methods, but without full codebase it's hard for me to tell what's wrong here.

Comment: @H2CO3 If I understand correctly `touchesEnded:` should not even being called. Why forward touches to the next responder then?

Comment: @hoha if you don't, you'll experience the exact same error OP encountered.

Comment: [yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourselector) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside] - Give that a try if you mange to get it to appear on top of your other subviews.

Comment: @H2CO3 In situation OP has described button should stand before `GameBoardView` in the responder chain (because either it's nested deeper or lies outside the view), so `touches...` methods are irrelevant here.